# Manage list of subjects (show, delete, add) in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code. It loops a menu, from which you can select whether you want to add a subject, see all subjects or delete a subject. Is there anything style- or functionality-wise to add or correct?

```
def add_subject(subjects):
    
    # ask for subject to add
    add = input("\nWhat subject do you want to add? ")

    # if subject not already in list, add subject
    subjects.append(add) if not add in subjects else print("\nSubject already in list.")

def show_subjects(subjects):
    
    # show all subjects
    print("\nThese are your subjects: ", subjects)

def delete_subject(subjects):
    
    # ask for subject to delete
    delete = input("\nPlease enter subject to delete: ")

    # if subject is in list, delete subject
    subjects.remove(delete) if delete in subjects else print("\nSubject not found.")

def main():
    
    # initialise list of sample subjects
    subjects = ["Math","Science","English"]

    # loop action cycle
    while 1:
        try:
            # ask user for selection
            selection = int(input("\nPlease enter option: \n(1) Add subject\n(2) Show all subjects\n(3) Delete a subject\n(4) Quit\n"))

            # call associated function
            if selection == 1:
                add_subject(subjects)
            elif selection == 2:
                show_subjects(subjects)
            elif selection == 3:
                delete_subject(subjects)
            elif selection == 4:
                break
            else:
                raise ValueError

        except ValueError:
            print("\nNot a viable option. Please pick 1, 2 or 3.")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 3):

## Clear the screen

Here is the terminal after three iterations
[image]

We can clean a lot of this up by simply doing

```
print(chr(27) + "[2J")
```

after every iteration.

```py
def clear_scr():
    print(chr(27) + "[2J")
```

Note that on adding this, you should also do

```py
input("Press any key to continue...")
```

After the user selects an option, this way the user can wait and see what is on the screen peacefully without the program interrupting

```py
def wait():
    input("Press any key to continue...")
    print(chr(27) + "[2J")
```

Or a better version that also prints a confirmation message

```py
def wait(message):
    input(f"{message}. Press any key to continue...")
    print(chr(27) + "[2J")



wait("Subject Added!")

>>> Subject Added! Press any key to coninue...
```

---

## Unnecessary comments

```py
# ask user for selection
selection = int(input("\nPlease enter option: \n(1) Add subject\n(2) Show all subjects\n(3) Delete a subject\n(4) Quit\n"))
```

A comment here is totally not required, it only makes the code look convoluted for no reason. What I do suggest is the usage of [docstrings](http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).

```py
def wait():
    """
    Wait for the user to press any key then clear the screen
    """
    ...
```

---

## Print the subjects in a better fashion

I added a few more subjects in your program. When I entered `Show all subjects`.

```
These are your subjects:  ['Math', 'Science', 'French', 'Computer', 'Hindi', 'Social Science', 'Spanish', 'English']
```

This isn't nice at all, I suggest you print one on each line, with numbering, something like

```
Subjects

1. Math
2. Science
3. French
3. Computer
...
```

```
def show_subjects(subjects):
    """
    print all the subjects line-by-line 
    """
    print("\n\nSubjects\n")
    for i in range(len(subjects)):
        print(f"{i+1}. {subjects[i]}")
```

---

## Don't use [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20programming%2C%20the%20term,be%20replaced%20with%20named%20constants)

```py
            if selection == 1:
                add_subject(subjects)
            elif selection == 2:
                show_subjects(subjects)
            elif selection == 3:
                delete_subject(subjects)
            elif selection == 4:
                break
            else:
                raise ValueError
```

`1`, `2`, `3`, and `4` are unnamed numeric constants here. They don't really really tell anything about what the branch does. What if it was instead

```py
            if selection == Choices.add.value:
                add_subject(subjects)
            elif selection == Choices.show.value:
                show_subjects(subjects)
            elif selection == Choices.delete.value:
                delete_subject(subjects)
            elif selection == Choices.quit.value:
                break
            else:
                raise ValueError
```

Without reading anything inside the if block, I can tell exactly what its going to do. That is an example of clean code.

You can achieve this by using an [enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html)

```py
from enum import Enum

class Choices(Enum):
    add = 1
    show = 2
    delete = 3
    quit = 4

print(Choices.add.value) 
>> 1

print(Choices.quit.value)
>> 4
```

---

## Colored text

This one is optional, but it adds a lot of meaning to your code :). 
You can use the [coloroma](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) module to color your text to different colors in an easy way. For example, when you find that the user has entered bad input, you can do

[image]

Isn't that great! The best part about it is that it is cross-platform

```py
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
print(Fore.RED + 'some red text')
print(Back.GREEN + 'and with a green background')
print(Style.DIM + 'and in dim text')
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
print('back to normal now')
```

You have a lot of options, it can help you customize the output a lot. Read the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/)

As suggested by @Reinderien, using the colorama library you can clear the screen too

```py
import colorama as cr
cr.init()

print(cr.ansi.clear_screen()) # clears the screen
```

## Re-written

```py
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
import colorama as cr
from enum import Enum

cr.init()


class Choices(Enum):
    add = 1
    show = 2
    remove = 3
    quit = 4


def wait(message = None):
    if message is None:
        input("Press any key to continue...")
    else:
        print(Fore.GREEN)
        print(Style.BRIGHT)

        print(message, end = '')

        print(Style.RESET_ALL)
        input("Press any key to continue...")

    print(cr.ansi.clear_screen())

def add_subject(subjects):
    add = input("\nWhat subject do you want to add? ")
    if add not in subjects:
        subjects.append(add)
        wait("Subject Added!")
    else:
        print("Subject already present")
        wait()


def show_subjects(subjects):
    print("Subjects\n")
    print(Fore.YELLOW)
    print(Style.BRIGHT)
    for i in range(len(subjects)):
        print(f"{i+1}. {subjects[i]}")
    wait()

def delete_subject(subjects):
    delete = input("\nPlease enter subject to delete: ")
    if delete not in subjects:
        print("Subject not found")
        wait()
    else:
        subjects.remove(delete)
        wait("Subject removed!")

def main():
    subjects = ["Math","Science","English"]
    while True:
        try:
            selection = int(input("\nPlease enter option: \n(1) Add subject\n(2) Show all subjects\n(3) Delete a subject\n(4) Quit\n"))
            if selection == Choices.add.value:
                add_subject(subjects)
            elif selection == Choices.show.value:
                show_subjects(subjects)
            elif selection == Choices.remove.value:
                delete_subject(subjects)
            elif selection == Choices.add.value:
                break
            else:
                raise ValueError

        except ValueError:
            print(Fore.RED)
            print("\nNot a viable option. Please pick 1, 2 or 3.")
            print(Style.RESET_ALL)
            wait()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image: g]

Comment: I think `dataclass` over enum for `Choices` here would be cleaner

Comment: @hjpotter92 I have to research more about data classes before recommending it, can you give an example?

Comment: Adding coloured text and clearing the screen are fine, but tightly coupling to raw ANSI escape sequences is a bad idea. Consider using something like https://github.com/tartley/colorama instead.

Comment: @AryanParekh as an example: https://tio.run/##Rc29CoUwDAXgvU@RURfBn0kQBJ@k2EgLamoTkfv0vaVYzBByvuHE/8TS2ce4BTrAaNHrrpmRwR2egnyklJq/kDcsltyKPCpIo40ZwZ0CE7QZ2NJTpMticEfBYn2263ZSZEhPfEh39TY3qbSO8Q8 (and the docs: https://devdocs.io/python~3.8/library/dataclasses#dataclasses.dataclass)

Comment: @Reinderien yes I've recommended the colorama library, what's wrong?

Comment: You're not making enough use of it. `print(chr(27) + "[2J")` should be a call to `colorama` as well.

Comment: @Reinderien Added the `clear_screen` call from the colorama library, I didn't expect it to have it earlier

Comment: Fine; though I'd edit your explicit escape sequences to show the same. Anyway.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Thanks! Ill check it out

Comment: Why not use `for i, subject in enumerate(subjects, 1)` rather than `for i in range(len(subjects))`? That is usually considered more pythonic and cleans up your print statement: `print(f"{i}. {subject}")`

Comment: @Energya Yes, I didn't think of that, do you mind if I add it to my answer?

Comment: Of course, go ahead